# How can I calculate the direction of an MKRouteStep in MapKit

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I'm getting a `MKDirectionsResponse`, which contains a few `MKRoute`s and inside them are a few `MKRouteStep`s.

Now inside an `MKRouteStep` are a few things as defined by the `MKRouteStep` class. Namely `instructions`, `polyline` etc. What is not defined however, is something called a `GEOStep`. Perusing the private API I can see it contains a member variable - `_maneuverType`.

`_maneuverType` carries an Int. In this case, it was 17. I would like to know if there is an index somewhere that says what this number indicates. (turn left, turn right, fly etc)

I need to know what the next instruction is for some navigation arrows. So language-less indication would be ideal and also not having to pick individual words from the instruction string.

[image: Screenshot of the <code>MKRoute</code>]

Comment: Sounds like you want to use private API?

Comment: Don't think this is private? If so, I guess I would have to go with Google Maps or MapBox or something else :(

Comment: I don't know much about MapKit but I do know looking at the header file none of the properties you list are there leading me to believe what you want is private API...

Comment: But it might be better to rephrase your question so its easier understood exactly what you want to achieve. There may be another way:)

Comment: Agree with @DanielGalasko. The apple documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKRouteStep_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKRouteStep) only lists a few properties and maneuverType isnt one of them. This smells like private API

Comment: @DanielGalasko hmm yeah I guess you might be right :( I've edited my question a little - is that a bit more clear?

Comment: I only managed to find this [tutorial]( https://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/ios7-day-by-day-day-13-route-directions-with-mapkit) that leads me to believe you might need to use the polyline of each step to determine direction...

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @Jan I just resorted to MapBox eventually

Answer (score 0):

There's a good chance chance it aligns with the enum values you see here:

https://developers.arcgis.com/net/phone/api-reference/html/T_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Tasks_NetworkAnalyst_RouteManeuverType.htm

Assuming Apple are using GIS standards.

Comment: Just tested it out and with Apple returning a `_maneuverType` of 4 and instructing me to do a U-Turn, it doesnt seem to correspond with the GIS standard (which would be 9 for a U-Turn)

Comment: Ok, must be some values they use internally